# RealmCollectionChange modified parameter has multiple indexes when only one object is modified

Tags: swift, realm

**Issue:** When a single object is modified in Realm, the modified parameter in a RealmCollectionChange is passed multiple indexes

**Details:** Given a Person object which has a list of Dog Objects and a Dog object that has an owner property of type Person

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var owner: Person?
}

class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

then a single person is created with two dogs

```
let person0 = Person()
person0.personName = "Leroy"

let dog0 = Dog()
dog0.name = "Spot"
dog0.owner = person0

let dog1 = Dog()
dog1.name = "Rex"
dog1.owner = person0

person0.dogs.append(dog0)
person0.dogs.append(dog1)

//write person0 to Realm which creates the person and two dogs
```

and the observe function

```
func doObserve() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(Dog.self)

    notificationToken = results.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in

        switch changes {
        case .initial:
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            for index in deletions {
                print("deleted object at index: \(index)")
            }

            for index in insertions {
                print("inserted object at index: \(index)")
            }

            for index in modifications {
                print("modified object at index: \(index)")
                let object = results[index]
                print(object) //prints dog0 and dog1 when dog1 is mod
            }
        case .error(let error):
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

then, if the Realm file is opened with RealmBrowser (or using code in the App) and Dog1 (Rex) name is changed to Fluffy, the modified parameter within the RealmCollectionChange contains two indexes, 0 and 1 even though only dog1 (index 1) was modified.

Is this behavior correct and if so, is there another option to just get the (index to the) object that was modified?

(or am I totally missing something obvious?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify dog1, dog0.owner.dogs[1] has changed, so Realm reports that dog0 is modified as well.

There's currently no way to manually specify how deep of a path you want Realm to check for changes to an object, but you may be able to sidestep this behavior by changing `Person`'s `List<Dog>` to `LinkingObjects<Dog>`, as inverse relationships are not followed when checking for changes. This also would remove the need to set the relationship in two places.

Comment: I had to take some time to digest and try out this answer and your suggestion of using *LinkingObjects<Dog>* instead of manually creating an inverse relationship seems to work and only reports the index to the dog that was modified. Thank you!

Comment: The problem this is causing is that sometimes we need to know a dog's owners, and sometimes we need to know an owner's dogs. If we set up our objects with what you suggested we can no longer query the owners to see if they have a certain dog. We would need to do the queries from the Dog object? i.e. if we want to print a list of owners and their dogs, we would *not* be able to read in all of the owner objects and iterate over them and print each one.

Comment: You can query on a LinkingObjects in all the same ways as on a List (i.e. you can do `realm.objects(Person.self).filter("ANY dogs = %@", dog)` even if Dogs is a `LinkingObjects<Dog>`).

Comment: Thanks for the the explanation and yes, that works perfectly. For future reader reference, if the Person object has a dogs = LinkingObjects<Dog> property, and you want to find the owner of the dog with the name of 'Rex' this will work;  results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("ANY dogs.name == %@", "Rex")